# My EditAccount POST request get login failed but my Login Request is successful Java RestAssured

Tags: java, api, post, automated-tests, rest-assured

This `edit` request need an access_token that was given back when I login. But when I use code below, it didn't work. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sy9l.png). When I used login test with this email and password, it received code and message meaning that I have logged in successfully and received an access_token. But when I used this token for my edit account request, it received "login failed". Is there any way to do it?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals;

import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class EditTest {

    Map < String, Object > map = new HashMap < String, Object > ();

    private final String JSON = "application/json";

    @Test
    public void TestCase01() {

        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();

        baseURI = "https://auction-app3.herokuapp.com/api";

        JSONObject req = new JSONObject();

        req.put("email", "ntv@gmail.com");
        req.put("password", "123456");

        Response res = given().contentType(JSON).
        body(req.toJSONString()).
        when().
        post("/login");

        System.out.println(res.getBody().asString());

        JsonPath jp = res.jsonPath();
        int code = jp.getInt("code");
        String ACCESS_TOKEN = jp.getString("access_token");


        request.put("access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
        request.put("email", "ninhvinh@gmail.com");
        request.put("password", "123456");
        request.put("re_pass", "123456");
        request.put("address", "MyAddress");
        request.put("name", "MyName");
        request.put("phone", "09090909090");
        request.put("avatar", null);

        Response response = given().contentType(JSON).body(request.toJSONString()).when().post("/edit");

        System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());

        JsonPath jpath = response.jsonPath();
        assertNotEquals(jpath.getInt("code"), 1000);

    }
}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

- First, you haven't extracted the `access_token`, it must be

```
String ACCESS_TOKEN = jp.getString("access_token");
```

--->

```
String ACCESS_TOKEN = jp.getString("data.access_token");
```

- Second, `access_token` should be in header, not request body. So remove

```
request.put("access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

and add one header.

```
Response response = given().contentType(JSON)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .body(request.toJSONString()).when().post("/edit");
```

Result:

[image]

One more issue is `assertNotEquals(jpath.getInt("code"), 1000);`, but it's not addressing problem in this question.

If my answer works for you, please accept it as correct answer.